# Are Bayesian approches used for classification (supervised) or for clustering (unsupervised)?

Tags: bayesian, classification, clustering, naive-bayes, nonparametric-bayes

Are Bayesian approaches (static and dynamic) used for classification (which is supervised) or for clustering (which is unsupervised)? or can they be used for both ?

I even see that for instance to compute the likelihood they need the class labels of data, so I was thinking that it is only convenient for supervised cases where we have the class labels

Comment: Well, you can obviously use Bayesian approaches for various things, so why would they not be usable for learning? Also I recommend looking at clustering *NOT* from a learning perspective. It is not about learning (as in "recall") but about exploration. Many clustering methods will not "learn" anything, they are nothing but a (useful) statistical method. Don't follow the AI view, which is very biased towards machine learning.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I didn't talked about "learning", my question was edited by someone else. I want to know if this approaches are more convenient for supervised classification, or rather they more convenient for the unsupervised one (clustering).

Comment: What I'm say is that "the unsupervised one" is actually something quite different. It is not classification, because there are no classes, you want to find something new instead. Just my 2¢. Nevertheless, **you can use Bayesian approaches for just about anything**, your question is too imprecise.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse which "something new" will you find with clustering ? for me it is like an unsupervised classification. Do you have some concrete examples on "somethings new" that you can find ?

Nevertheless, concerning the Bayesian approaches, I even see that for instance to compute the likelihood they need the class labels of data, so I was thinking that it is only convenient for supervised cases where we have the class labels.

Comment: It's in how you use the data. This is entirely different. In classification, you want to assign objects to the existing classes. In clustering, you want to analyze the clusters found, whether they make any sense to you. So the value is not in single objects being assigned one way or another, but in the global *structure*. And you want to find structure that you did not know before, to get insight on your data. The most similar thing probably is decision trees, here you also get insight on your data by actually looking at the tree.

Comment: As for bayesian statistics: forget about the f... labels (classification tends to put this limit on your thinking). It can be any condition. If A is in 1..10, then B is in 10..20 - boom, you can compute Bayesian statistics. You do not need class labels. All you need are **sets**. They don't even need to be disjoint. You could make them fuzzy or rough.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Ok in classification you want to assign objects to the existing classes, so how do you call a clustering method where we make use of the class labels (to help us) during the clustering process ? do you call it supervised clustering ?


It is ok for Bayesian methods. It will be good if you can make an answer with your comments. I'll accept it.

Comment: There are things such as semi-supervised clustering and constraint clustering. You could use your existing class labels as constratints (e.g. if they are labeled differently, they should not link) I guess. But I focus on the truly unsupervised approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayesian methods are very general. While there obviously is Naive Bayes, it can of course be used outside the "labeled data" domains.

Bayesian statistic is often defined on sets. The sets could be labels, but they could also be anything else. I figure you could use Bayesian statistics to test for mutual information, for example. So this common use of statistics - sets or predicates, and probably generalizable to fuzzy sets - can be used in various disciplines. After all, I can define predicates such as $x_3 < 7$ and then talk about the probability $P(x_5 > 3 | x_3 < 7)$ depending on a prior of $P(x_3 < 7)$ etc.